# Why am I getting a 'System.TypeInitializationException' when I create an Oracle connection in my .Net WCF web service?

Tags: .net, wpf, wcf, oracle, odac

I'm currently working on implementing a WCF service which talks to an Oracle 10g database on the backend. When I attempt to connect to the database from within my service, I get the following exception: `System.TypeInitializationException`.

- I'm running on a windows 7 (64 bit machine).
- I'm using VS 2010.
- I'm using Oracle 10g on the backend.
- I'm the Oracle.DataAccess.dll (ODP.Net) from the following installed
  instance

  ```
   c:\oracle\product\10.2.0\.....\ODP.NET\bin\1.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
  ```
- I've included this DLL in the references for my WCF service.
- I've included this service as a project within my VS WPF solution.
- The service starts up automatically when I start my WPF application
  in VS 2010.

At runtime I see the following output in my debug output window:

> 'WcfSvcHost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
> 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Oracle.DataAccess\1.102.2.20__89b483f429c47342\Oracle.DataAccess.dll'
> A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException'
> occurred in Oracle.DataAccess.dll

Sure enough, I look at the exception details in the debugger and I see the following information (this occurs when I attempt to create a new ORACLE connection):

> "The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection'
> threw an exception." InnerException   {"The provider is not compatible
> with the version of Oracle client"}   System.Exception
> {Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException}

#### A Little Background:

I'm basically migrating my data layer to a WCF service. The same service layer previously existed in a WinForm application. Everything works fine in my WinForm application. I include the same reference to the Oracle.DataAccess.dll and all my reads/writes with the database work fine.

Is there something obviously different between the WCF and WinForm access/use of the DLL?
Is there some limitation I'm unaware of?
Is there an issue running this through VS2010 in the debugger?

I have absolutely no idea what is going on here. Any hints/direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is nothing special on the .NET side you need to be aware of.
Some of the reasons for this specific error are:

1. Your application targets .NET 4 but you only have ODP.NET for .NET 2 or even .NET 1 installed
2. You are making use of a local Oracle Instant client and are missing some of the unmanaged DLLs.

---

Actually, your exception message states that it tried to load the Oracle.DataAccess.dll from the GAC with the version number 1.102.2.20. This seems to be the **.NET 1** version of ODP.NET as the version for .NET 2 has the number **2**.102.2.20 and for .NET 4 it has the number **4**.102.2.20.

Maybe your Winforms application had a version of Oracle.DataAccess.dll in its bin folder and was using that instead the one in the GAC?

---

These problems are the reason why I switched to a local Oracle Instant client in my projects. This adds 130 MB to my deployment but it doesn't matter as it's all corporate software.

Comment: As a test, I added the ODAC reference directly to my WPF application and was able to connect successfully. This leads me to believe it's somehow an issue with my WCF service. When I run through VS2010, the WCF service gets hosted through WcfSvsHost.exe. It feels like the issue is somehow related to that?

Comment: @JohnB: It might very well be the issue, yes. Try copying the Oracle.DataAccess.dll to the bin directory of the WCF service and see if that helps.

Comment: You mean into the bin directory of the service I created, not the bin directory of the WCFSvcHst.exe, correct?  I did that already and got the same results. I'm working on installing the 11.2 client and then 11.2 ODAC. I'm assuming ll.2 client will work with 10g DB?

Comment: @JohnB: Yes, the 11.2 client works with a 10g database. No problems there. I meant the bin directory of your service, yes. Very strange indeed. You might want to try something else: Reference ODAC in your WCF service project and in the properties of the reference first verify that it shows the correct version (starting with **4.**). Second, change "Specific version" from "False" to "True"

Comment: Success. Success. Success.
Thanks for your help/comments/feedback.
I finally went with ODAC X64 11.2 and so far it seems to work fine.

Thanks again,
JohnB